# Creating QField form where answer for drop-down field opens linked drop-down field

Tags: qgis, qfield, dropdownlist

I'm trying to create a qfield form where an answer for one drop-down field determines the  next field's drop-down options. Specifically, I want a value map with the options  Sedimentary, Volcaniclastic, Volcanic, Plutonic,  and Metamorphic. I want the value that is chosen there to determine the following value map.

For instance, choosing sedimentary would make the next field provide a value map with all of the sedimentary rock options.

If this is possible, then how do I do it?